# How to write floating point intensity into images? And then to read it back as floating point again?

Tags: java, image-processing, floating-point, tiff, steganography

I'm currently working with ***Java***, so if there's any function that I can work with Java itself then it'll be great.(Any other language is also fine as long as it works) I *cannot convert the floating point to int* because doing so I'll be losing the information that I had embedded in it. ***(My aim is to achieve Steganography so it'll lose its purpose***).

Comment: A pixel value can be written as 0-1 floating point or 0-255. But I doubt floating point is how they achieve steganography. I bet it should work with 0-255

Comment: i am using kekre's wavelet transform to do it, and to get back the original image we have to perform some computations, wherein we get the floating point intensity.(i am using lsb with kwt to do so)

Comment: LSB *what*? Are you saying you're modifying the least significant bit of a float?

Comment: @Reti43 no no, Im actually embedding the message in lsb of transform of the image matrix which contain integer values, then i apply the inverse transform which gives me the floating point and i need to embed those values back into the image. So i need a way to do it